# How can I prevent "chain suck"?

Tags: chain, gears, damage

I know what the above is: when your chain bunches when you change gears & the bunch runs through the front derailleur and wrenches it. This damage is pretty much irreparable, and has cost me far too much money. How can I stop this?

Comment: Chain suck can be due to any/all of several factors: 1) A poorly-lubed, rusty chain, with "frozen" links, 2) insufficient rear derailer spring tension, or a bent/maladjusted derailer, 3) worn, "hooked" sprockets (especially rear sprockets).  Normally, hooking is the main cause, but if it it occurs only on shifting then the derailer may be the main problem.

Comment: I keep the chain well lubed, and there's no rust visible. However, the sprockets are as old as the bike, about 5 years. Should I consider investing in new rear sprockets?

Comment: However, the latest damage occurred as I was wheeling the bike backwards into the garage. Does that make it more likely to be the sprockets?

Comment: I generally say that a rear cassette is good for about 5000 miles.  If you've had the bike for 5 years you could easily be beyond that.  Also, I forgot to mention that chain wear can be a factor -- a chain is good for about 2000 miles.  Replace both, and have a bike shop check the wear on the front sprockets as well (they should have a special gauge).

Comment: See also: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7107/what-causes-chain-suck